# Unconnected sets.

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm simply looking for a simple explanation of the following problem. I've read a few articles regarding connected and unconnected sets, but am still a little confused. So, why are the set of complex numbers $z$ such that $|z+1|<1 $ or $|z-1|<1$ is not connected? Why are $|z+1|<1 $ and $|z-1|\le1$ connected?

Thank you.

Comment: To be clear, you're asking why is the UNION of the two open disks $|z+1|<1$ and $|z-1|<1$ disconnected but the same union with closed disks connected?

Comment: $z = 0$ is a point in common between $|z+1| \le 1$ and $|z-1| \le 1$  But $z = 0$ is not a member of $|z+1| < 1$ or $|z-1| < 1$  nor are there any other common elements.

Comment: @DougM: That's true, but I don't think that clinches connectedness. Two sets can be disjoint and their union still connected. e.g. $[0,1) \cup [1,2]$.

Comment: @WB-man I'm not quite sure, the problem I'm looking at simply says what I wrote. It does give the hint that they're two open circles.

Answer (score 1):

A set $D\subseteq \Bbb C$ is connected iff you can joint any two points in $D$ by a continuous curve which stays in $D$. I hope you can see that this implies that any disk in the complex plane is connected (just join any two points in the disk by a straight line segment), so the two disks $A = \{z\in \Bbb C :|z-1|<1\}$ and $B = \{z\in \Bbb C :|z+1|<1\}$ are connected.

Consider the connectedness of $A\cup B$, noting $A$ and $B$ are disjoint. There is no way to draw a continuous curve from $A$ to $B$ without it leaving $A \cup B$ at some point so $A\cup B$ is disconnected.

If you close one of the disks, it will contain $0$ which is on the boundary of both sets, so you can now join $A$ and $B$ with a curve which passes through $0$. Hence the union of one disk with the closure of another is connected.

The notion of the connectedness of a set derives from topology. I have been talking about path-connectnedess, but in the complex plane, path connected is the same as connected and I find it easier to intuitively understand why sets in the complex plane are connected.

Comment: So this makes complete sense, which is why I'm a bit confused. The problem asks why $|z+1|<1 $ and $|z-1|<1$ are not connected. These are questions my professor writes on his own, does this mean his statement is false? He's done this multiple times this semester, so it wouldn't put it past me.

Comment: Yeah, they are connected

Comment: This contradicts Michael Blane's comment, why is his incorrect?

Comment: I think you're misreading @Bernard8 's answer. Notice they say that $A$ and $B$ are connected, but that their union is not.

Comment: I apologize, I actually made a mistake in my original question. I fixed it now. The question reads "Why are $|z+1|<1$ and $|z−1|≤1$ connected? " instead. But, this still seems to be incorrect. From what I understand, my professor has the question backward. The second set of inequalities is not connected, while the first one is. Am I correct in saying this?

Comment: That was weird, I apologize again.

Comment: No problem @Kosta : ) I see now that the comment is the same as the question. The sets are indeed connected. Try drawing the circles in the plane.

Comment: So, both sets of circles, the first being $|z+1|<1 $ and $|z-1|<1$ and the second being $|z+1|<1 $ and $|z-1|\le1$, are connected? I think I understand why they are, I just want to make sure my professor did indeed make a mistake in his question before I bring it up to him.

Comment: @Kosta Even though this has been going on for a while I'll pick up where they left off: The open disk $|z-1| < 1$ is connected. The open disk $|z+1| <1$ is connected. The union of these two disks is *not* connected. In contrast, the union of the closed disk $|z-1|\le 1$ and the open disk $|z+1| < 1 $ *is* connected.

Answer (score 1):

Let $B_{r}(z)$ be the open ball centered at $z\in\mathbb{C}$ with radius $r$. Consider the two open balls $B_{1}(-1)$ and $B_{1}(1)$. The first is the set of points with $|z+1|<1$ and the second is the set of points with $|z-1|<1$. Clearly $B_{1}(-1)$ and $B_{1}(1)$ are both connected as open balls in $\mathbb{C}\cong\mathbb{R}^2$. Notice that the two balls are lying tangent to each other at the origin, so if there is a path from the first ball to the second, then it must pass through $0$. But $0$ is not contained in either set, so it is not contained in their union. Therefore there is no path connecting the two balls, so they cannot be connected.

On the other hand, the second set in question is the union of the closure of $B_{1}(1)$ with $B_{1}(-1)$, which contains $0$, so a path can be constructed from one ball to the other, meaning that they are connected.

Comment: Your response seems to contradict Bernard8's answer.

Comment: I think we agree. We both show that the two open balls/disks are connected, but that their union is not. Then we show that the closed balls/disks have a connected union.

Comment: Wait. $B_1(1/2)$ has radius $1$ and is centered at $1/2$, so on the real line, it extends from $-1/2$ to $3/2$. I’m sure that you meant $B_1(-1)$ and $B_1(1)$.

Comment: Yes! That is what I meant. Thanks. Will correct later tonight.